# Количество повторяющихся элементов в списке

Tags: python

Есть массив, в котором куча повторяющихся элементов. Мне надо вывести содержимое конкретного элемента этого массива и сколько таких же элементов в нём (вывести цифру).
Пример массива:

```
array = ["Bob", "Alex", "Bob", "John"]
```

(типа 2 Боба и т.д.)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Самый простой способ подсчитать количество вхождений всех элементов - воспользоваться встроенным классом [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) из модуля [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html):

```
In [4]: from collections import Counter

In [5]: array = ["Bob", "Alex", "Bob", "John"] 

In [6]: c = Counter(array)

In [7]: c
Out[7]: Counter({'Bob': 2, 'Alex': 1, 'John': 1})

In [8]: c['Bob']
Out[8]: 2

In [9]: c['Unknown']
Out[9]: 0
```

Comment: Как получить 0 элемент в Counter({'Bob': 2, 'Alex': 1, 'John': 1})?
c[0] возвращает в итоге 0

Comment: Из документации: `As a dict subclass, Counter Inherited the capability to remember insertion order.`. Это значит, что `next(iter(Counter({'Bob': 2, 'Alex': 1, 'John': 1}).values()))` вернет `2` (начиная с версии 3.7). Однако `.values` возвращает `view`, который не поддерживает random access по индексу, это значит вам придется итерироваться до N элемента чтобы получить его значение. Поэтому на практике будет правильнее держать соответствие `keys: index -> key` и доставать как `c[keys[0]]`.

Answer (score 3):

Есть метод [list.count](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html)

```
>>> array.count("Bob")
2
>>> array.count("John")
1
>>> dict((x, array.count(x)) for x in set(array) if array.count(x) > 1)
{'Bob': 2}
```

Comment: это квадратичный алгоритм. Если заранее не известно, что длина array мала, то предпочтительнее линейный алгоритм, такой как в решении с Counter, использовать. Даже для маленьких array,  если особых причин нет, следует Counter предпочитать здесь.

Answer (score 2):

Например, вот так:

```
array = ["Bob", "Alex", "Bob", "John"];
result = {i: array.count(i) for i in array};
```

И вопрос, как тут вывести ключ по максимальному значению?

Comment: сорян...перенос пропустил...))

Comment: Это ворос или ответ?

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/209853)

Comment: @AndrewHobbit , почему не содержится?

Comment: Как же не содержится?))
За вопрос снизу извиняюсь))) 
И..кстати разобрался)) если кому надо - расскажу)

Answer (score 1):

Вообще говоря, это reduce-задача. Но в Python'е крайне слабые средства для операций с ассоциативными массивами (`dict`). В частности, два таких массива нельзя просто так взять и сложить. Придётся сначала разложить их на кортежи (`tuple`), затем сложить, а в конце обратно соединить. В результате однострочник, который мог бы выглядеть достойно, будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: dict(x.items()+[(y,x[y]+1 if y in x else 1)]), array, dict())
```

Comment: Честное слово, не нужно так писать на Питоне. Обратите внимание: в стандартной библиотеке есть модуль collections, а в нём Counter.

Comment: @idlesign Я в курсе. Даже специально сделал оговорку о том, что мне самому не нравится это решение. Про Counter тоже в курсе.

Comment: Гм, тогда двойне непонятно, зачем предлагать использовать ударниковые свойства пульверизатора, не предлагая при этом молоток.

Comment: @idlesign Молоток предложат и без меня. Я вижу свою задачу в том, чтобы предлагать небанальные решения.

Answer (score 1):

в качестве варианта

```
array = ["Bob", "Alex", "Bob", "John"]

array_d = {}.fromkeys(array, 0)
for a in array:
    array_d[a] += 1

print(array_d)
```

или

```
array_d = {}
for a in array:
    try: array_d[a] += 1
    except KeyError: array_d[a] = 1
```

Comment: Стоит `{}.fromkeys` на `dict.fromkeys` заменить. Оба работают, но fromkeys это метод класса, поэтому через экземпляр (`{}`) без необходимости лучше не вызывать. Дополнительно, это решение два раза обходит array. Вариант с Counter однопроходной (что произвольный итератор позволяет использовать).

Answer (score 1):

Если вдруг интересует вывод не конкретного имени, а вообще, какое само часто повторяется, то в функции max() можно сравнить строки количественно, а не лексикографически:

```
array = ["Bob", "Alex", "Bob", "John", "Jack", "Will", "Jacob", "Grace", "John", "David", "Bob"]
print(max(set(array), key=lambda x: array.count(x)))
```