# Получить все повторяющиеся элементы списка

Tags: python, списки

Есть `list` `A`, в котором некоторые строки повторяются.

Как получить список всех повторяющихся строк? То есть необходимо удалить из списка все уникальные значения. Как-то так.

Предполагаю некоторый способ.

Получаем список `B`, исключив все повторения в `A`:

```
B = list(set(A))
```

Каким образом теперь можно вычесть из `A` список `B` в абсолютном виде (поэлементно)? Чтобы получить искомый список.

Comment: похожий вопрос: [Количество повторяющихся элементов в списке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/418982/23044)

Comment: если в дубликате ответ не нашли. То обновите вопрос и явно укажите в чём разница (к примеру, [попробуйте `non_uniq()` функцию](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621477/23044)).

Answer (score 2):

```
for_stack = lambda array: sorted(list(set([x for x in array if array.count(x) > 1])))
print(for_stack(['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c']))
```

**Результат:**

```
['a', 'b']
```

С повторами:

```
for_stack = lambda array: sorted([x for x in array if array.count(x) > 1])
```

**Результат:**

```
['a', 'a', 'b', 'b']
```

Answer (score 1):

один из многих способов:

```
In [172]: lst = ['aaa','bbb','ccc','aaa','ccc','zzz']

In [173]: from collections import Counter

In [174]: c = Counter(lst)

In [175]: c
Out[175]: Counter({'aaa': 2, 'bbb': 1, 'ccc': 2, 'zzz': 1})

In [176]: [x for x in c.keys() if c[x] > 1]
Out[176]: ['aaa', 'ccc']
```

если надо с повторами:

```
In [177]: [x for x in lst if c[x] > 1]
Out[177]: ['aaa', 'ccc', 'aaa', 'ccc']
```