# Покер на Python

Tags: python

Даны 5 целых чисел. Среди них:

- если одинаковы 5, то вывести "Impossible", иначе
- если одинаковы 4, то вывести "Four of a Kind", иначе
- если одинаковы 3 и 2, то вывести "Full House", иначе
- если есть 5 последовательных, то вывести "Straight", иначе
- если одинаковы 3, то вывести "Three of a Kind", иначе
- если одинаковы 2 и 2, то вывести "Two Pairs", иначе
- если одинаковы 2, то вывести "One Pair", иначе
- вывести "Nothing".

Входные данные:
В первой строке находятся 5 чисел через пробел. Все числа от 1 до 13 включительно.

Выходные данные:
Выводится одна строка - результат анализа.

Прошу, хоть дайте подсказки как делать.

Вот что получается пока:

```py
import random
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
numbers = (str(random.choices(a_list, k=5))) 
print(numbers)
```

Comment: Часть решения вашего вопроса может быть здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/418982/Количество-повторяющихся-элементов-в-списке

Answer (score 2):

```py
    import random

    def resultOfTurn(results, cards):
        #Функция resultOfTurn() — возвращает результат хода игрока. В качестве параметров функции resultOfTurn() используются results  и cards. Где results — словарь возможных результатов, а cards — список из 5-ти случайных целочисленных значений. 
        print(cards, '\n')

        if 3 in [cards.count(c) for c in cards] and 2 in [cards.count(c) for c in cards]:
            #Если одинаковы 3 и 2.
            return results['3,2']
        elif len([c for c in [cards.count(c) for c in cards] if c == 2]) == 4:
            #Если одинаковы 2 и 2.
            return results['2,2']
        elif cards == sorted(cards):
            #Если есть 5 последовательных.
            return results['sequence']
        else:
            #Наибольший результат.
            return results[max([cards.count(c) for c in cards])]

    #Словарь возможных результатов, а также список 5-ти случайных значений целого типа.
    dictionaryOfResults = {'sequence': 'Straight', 5: 'Impossible', 4: 'Four of a Kind', '3,2': 'Full House', 3: 'Three of a Kind', '2,2': 'Two Pairs', 2: 'One Pair', 1: 'Nothing'}
    cards = random.choices(list(range(1, 14)), k=5)

    print(resultOfTurn(dictionaryOfResults, cards))
```

Вывод:

**[12, 7, 12, 1, 4]**

One Pair

Comment: Если питон позволяет в одной строчке присваивать значение нескольким переменным, то это совсем не означает, что так нужно делать в каждом случае.

Comment: Возможно я действительно часто пользуюсь множественным присваиванием. Пожалуй соглашусь с вами.